# What does "low bar to clear" mean?

Tags: meaning

It is from [Crash Course Meadia Literacy](https://youtu.be/Be-A-sCIMpg). It is at around 5 minute and 2 second. Here is the context:

> This one can be **a pretty low bar to clear**. As we know, our mind loves to accept the easiest to understand info as the right info because it is convenient. Which is why we move onto accuracy.

As the [Urban Dictionary](https://youtu.be/Be-A-sCIMpg) says *low bar* means a very low standard, but what confuses me is the word *clear*. Does the host mean that it is a pretty low bar to get rid of?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This is a metaphor from track and field—specifically jumping events. In high jumps and pole vaults a 'bar' is moved progressively higher and the jumper must 'clear' it: jump over it without touching it (or at least not making enough contact to knock it down). See [Collins](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/clear), definitions 16 and 18:

16. *adjective*

    > If something or someone is **clear** of something else, it is not touching it or is a safe distance away from it.
    >
    > > *As soon as he was clear of the terminal building he looked round.* [+ *of*]
    > >     *She placed a towel on a cluster of rocks just clear of the tidemark.*
    > >     *He lifted him clear of the deck with one arm.*

18 *verb*

> If an animal or person **clears** an object or clears a certain height, they jump over the object, or over something that height, without touching it.
>
> > *He was the first vaulter to clear 6.00 metres.*

A *low bar to clear* is thus an easy obstacle to jump over.

Comment: A minor quibble as one who frequently *brushed* the bar and then watched anxiously as it quivered. *Touching* is allowed - as long as the bar remains in place.

Comment: It may be worth noting that Google Books claims over 1400 instances of the sequence ***a pretty low bar***. My guess is that almost *all* of them will be for this same (metaphorical) sense, but less than 10% are followed by ***to clear***. That's to say, I think the true "idiomatic" element that learners might struggle with is ***low bar*** - and the optional "clarifying" element ***to clear*** shouldn't represent a problem on the semantic front (if anything, it should only make the idiom *more* "transparent").

Comment: @FumbleFingers You'd think, and so would I . . . but in this case OP is specifically confused by *clear*.

Comment: Indeed. And had you not already posted this answer, I'd have been tempted to closevote for lack of research while adding a comment link to the relevant dictionary definition. Perhaps that's a bit harsh, but the metaphorical aspect of ***low bar*** here seems so obvious I find it hard to imagine that OP could be aware of the *effective meaning* without recognising the figurative / etymological background (which should therefore make it easy to identify the relevant sense of ***to clear***).

Comment: @FumbleFingers - I'm a native English speaker and I get tripped up on this one regularly because for whatever reason I think of the bar from a limbo dance first. The sense of which is more difficult, a high or low bar, is the reverse of track and field. However, in limbo or on the field, one still has to clear the bar.

Comment: @FumbleFingers So what you're saying is that you consider the research for this question to be a pretty low bar…